# existance of gradient conformal vector field on riemannian manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let ‎$ ‎(M,g)‎ $ ‎be a Riemannian manifold. A gradient conformal vector field on 
‎$ ‎M‎ $‎ is a conformal vector field ‎$ ‎X‎ $‎ which is at the same time the
gradient of a function on ‎‎$ ‎M‎ $ ‎:‎
\begin{equation}‎
‎X=‎\nabla f‎ ,‎ ‎L‎_{X}‎g=2‎\rho ‎g‎
\end{equation}‎‎
where $L‎$ is the Lie derivative.
Is there always gradient conformal vector field on $M$?
Thanks. ‎‎‎‎